# Is it possible to use fopen in iCloud folder?

Tags: ios, fopen, icloud

I'm trying to create a file directly in iCloud folder, and I'm facing that when I try to make an fopen to the iCloud folder, always returns 0x0

Is there anyway to do this? I know I should use UIDocument, or various protocols, but I just want a simple plain way to access that folder as if a normal folder was.

```
FILE* file;
NSURL tmp = [ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
char* folder = (char*) [[tmp absoluteString] fileSystemRepresentation];
sprintf(folder, "%s/file1.txt", folder);
file = fopen(folder, "rw+");
fprinf(file, "%s", "this is just an example");
fclose(file);
```

I've also tried the following folders manually:

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXXXX~com~name~app/Documents/file1.txt
//localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXXXX~com~name~app/Documents/file1.txt
/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXXXX~com~name~app/Documents/file1.txt
/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXXXX~com~name~app/Documents/file1.txt
/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXXXX.com.name.app/Documents/file1.txt
/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXX~com~name~app/Documents/file1.txt
/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXX.com.name.app/Documents/file1.txt
```

All of them have returned 0x0 as result of fopen() function call;

Thank you in advance.

PD: I've been successfully created a file using the NSFileManager class.